# UITextView not showing formatted text using attributedText property - JSQMessageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using `JSQMessageViewController` for chat in my project. Now my client wants to show formatted text in chat bubble. `JSQMessageViewController` have `UITextView` used for chat bubble message already. I'm trying to use `attributedText` property of it but its not working.
Following is my code:-

```
if let htmlData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) {
            
            do {
                let attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)                
                
                return attributedText
            } catch let e as NSError {
                print("Couldn't translate: \(e.localizedDescription) ")
            }
        }
        return NSAttributedString(string: "")
```

Assigning to text view :-
`_textView.attributedText = text;`

Following is the html received from web :-

```
"<p><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Hi There #Testing #formatting</span></p><p><strong class=\"ql-font-serif\">Bold text</strong></p><p><em class=\"ql-font-serif\">Italic text</em></p><p><strong class=\"ql-font-serif\"><em>Bold Italic text</em></strong></p><p><u class=\"ql-font-serif\">Underline text</u></p><p><s class=\"ql-font-serif\">Strike text</s></p><blockquote><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Quotes text</span></blockquote><h1><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 1</span></h1><h2><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 2</span></h2><p><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 3</span></p><h5><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 4</span></h5><h5><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 5</span></h5><h6><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Heading 6</span></h6><ol><li><span class=\"ql-font-serif\">Text</span></li><li>Text</li><li>Text</li><li>Text</li></ol><ul><li>Text</li><li>Text</li><li>Text</li></ul>"
```

This same code is working on other class which is having `UITextView` but not working on chat bubble class named `JSQMessagesCellTextView` which is also having `UITextView`

Comment: I'm trying to use attributedText property of it but its not working" WHat's your code? What's the rendering exactly?

Comment: @Larme stackoverflow not allowing to post too long question so not able to post the code.

Comment: I think you can share only the interesting part of the code, no? We don't need you whole project.

Comment: @Larme Edited the question. Please check now.

Comment: And where do you assign it to the textView ? Also, define "not working".

Comment: @Larme I am using same code on my other class which is having UITextView and its working perfectly. Its not working on chat bubble which is also having UITextView and class name is JSQMessagesCellTextView

Comment: @Priyanka  did you try to update the text with attributedText from  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: @SreerajVR Yes doing in same method only. ```cellForItemAtIndexPath```

Comment: @Priyanka then try to set  'cell.textView.attributedText' inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @SreerajVR I have tried that too but its not working. showing html only without formatting.